# magento 2.3 admin panel redirect to customer account section after login

Tags: magento2.3, redirect, admin-login

I'm facing some issue after login magneto2.3 admin account, its redirect to "My Account" Section.

Kindly have a look this type of issue and guide me.

https://prnt.sc/qnef67

Comment: if you are logged in for the first time after installation do check in the database with user name or unlock the user from CLI

Comment: @purnagattu,not first time, its running from last 2.5 years.

Comment: need to change the password , for security reason periodically Magento asks for password change.